# Algebraic Long Division

Tags: calculus

I have this fraction : $\frac{x^4}{x-1}$ and I need to integrate it. My strategy is to do long division however I have never learnt how to do this? I know the answer but I was wondering if anyone could walk me through? After lots of youtube tutorials I am still stuck!

If you have no time don't worry this is not urgent would just like to know! 
From someone who should know how to long divide by now......

Thank you!

Comment: see here http://mathematics.laerd.com/maths/algebraic-division-intro.php

Comment: Google "polynomial long division" for the general approach, but in this case, $$\frac{x^4}{x-1}=\frac{x^4-1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x-1}=x^3+x^2+x+1+\frac{1}{x-1}.$$

Comment: The special case of dividing a polynomial by a monic first degree polynomial is called *synthetic division* in high school algebra.

Comment: Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! Thank you everyone, http://mathematics.laerd.com/maths/algebraic-division-intro.php was very helpful :)